Reading datadog agentless logs on the datadog portal
I'm configuring Datadog logs via agentless serilog configuration (doc). The only information I provided is my Datadog API key.
Configuration:
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
             .WriteTo.DatadogLogs(
                    "API_KEY", 
                    configuration: new DatadogConfiguration() 
                    { 
                        Url = "http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com" 
                    })
             .CreateLogger();

        builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
        builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);

Then in the controller, I use logger through DI:
   _logger.LogInformation("Some logs");

However, I can't really find where I can see this logs in the Datadog portal?
Looking at Logs section (https://app.datadoghq.com/logs/onboarding) says that I need to configure one of the below:
* Server
* Container 
* Cloud
* Client
* Other

where in the client, I can't see c# language. I'm a bit confused where the logs I sent to the portal can be found?
Also, I'm not even sure that my configuration is correct because when I intentionally break the Datadog API_KEY configuration, the logging step itself doesn't fail (but I see that the only available provider inside logger is  Name = "Serilog", LogLevel = Trace, so it looks configured).
Any troubleshooting ideas would be helpful.

This question would be better asked to the DataDog support team. https://www.datadoghq.com/support/

Are you setting up for US region ? There is a different serilog sink config required for US region. Please follow the documentation. https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/csharp/?tab=serilog#agentless-logging-with-serilog-sink GithubRepo https://github.com/DataDog/serilog-sinks-datadog-logs/
